# Modality issue in SWT_AWT bridge

Tags: integration, swt, eclipse-rcp, awt

I am using EmbeddedSwingComposite (built on SWT_AWT bridge) which is mentioned in the following article :
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html

Though it says that using the above technique modality issues are resolved. But in my case there are still some modality issues left. I guess maybe becuause I am using JDK6 wherein Swing modality was changed.

Anybody with experience or any idea on this. Any further info please post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If any additional info is required, I can provide. 
Anyone with inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. My solution was to change the shell on the pop-up box / shell to an SWT shell, while keeping the children as Swing components. This sorts everything out completely, but might be incompatible with your existing APIs.